# Slow DNS lookup with Firefox on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, 18.04, firefox

Ubuntu 18.04 is up to date.  On Firefox, browsing seems to spend all of its time "looking up xyz".  Ubuntu 16.04 was much better. On the same hardware using Fedora 28 and Firefox, the web browsing time is excellent.

Tried Chrome, worked great. Reloaded Firefox, same results. Firefox version: Quantum 64.0 Mozilla Firefox for Ubuntu. Canonical - 1.0.

Tried using DNS servers Google and openDNS.  Not much help.

I am using x86_64, 4.4 GHz clock, 16 GB memory, SSD drives, 60 Mbit internet connection.

Until this gets fixed, I will have to use Fedora.

Comment: How strange, because my 18.04 with Firefox is very fast...so this does not seem like a universal problem. Please narrow the scope of your problem to determine if it's a networking stack problem or a Firefox problem..  "Not much help" does not really tell us anything.

Comment: Tried chrome, worked great. Reloaded firefox, same results.  Will stick with chrome.

Comment: Can you include the firefox version in your question?

Comment: The firefox with Ubuntu and my download are the same version: Firefox Quantum 64.0 Mozilla firefox for Ubuntu.  Canonical - 1.0

Comment: With Firefox 69.0.1, I have this same problem on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS. I spend a good few seconds looking at "looking up google.com" etc...

Comment: Check if you have ip6 enabled on your router and on your machine. If it's enabled on one (probably Ubuntu 18.04) and not the other you could be trying ip6 until that fails and then falling back on ip4. See [How to disable IPv6 address on Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver Linux](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-disable-ipv6-address-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux)

Answer (score 0):

In 2022 firefox has problems with IPv6 DNS lookups.

In firefox go to `about:config` and set value of `network.dns.disableIPv6` to true.

Comment: Hello. Since this question was asked 3 years ago I am not seeing how a current version of Firefox would have anything to do with it.